# Query a server for the existence of a record without the server knowing exactly what record was being queried for

Tags: javascript, hash, passwords, security

I've been thinking about services such as [pwnedlist.com](http://pwnedlist.com) and [shouldichangemypassword.com](http://shouldichangemypassword.com) and the fundamental problem with them - trust.

That is to say the user must trust that these services aren't going to harvest the submitted queries.

Pwnedlist.com offers the option to submit a SHA-512 hash of the users query which is a step forward but still leaks information if the query does exist in the database. That is, a malicious service would know that the given email address was valid (see also: why you should never click unsubscribe links in spam email).

The solution I came up with is as follows:

1) Instead of the user calculating and submitting the hash herself, the hash (I'll use the much simpler md5 in my example) is calculated via client side javascript:

```
md5("user@example.com") = "b58996c504c5638798eb6b511e6f49af"
```

2) Now, instead of transmitting the entire hash as a query to the server, only the first N bits are transmitted:

```
GET http://remotesite.com?query=b58996
```

3) The server responds with all hashes that exist in it's database that begin with the same N bits:

```
{
"b58996afe904bc7a211598ff2a9200fe",
"b58996c504c5638798eb6b511e6f49af",
"b58996443fab32c087632f8992af1ecc", 
...etc... }
```

4) The client side javascript compares the list of hashes returned by the server and informs the user whether or not her email address exists in the DB.
    *Since "b58996c504c5638798eb6b511e6f49af" is present in the server response, the email exists in the database - inform the user!*

Now, the obvious problem with this solution is that the user must trust the client side javascript to only transmit what it says it is going to transmit. Sufficiently knowledgable individuals however, would be able to verify that the query isn't being leaked (by observing the queries sent to the server). It's not a perfect solution but it would add to the level of trust if a user could (theoretically) verify that site functions as it says it does.

What does SO think of this solution? Importantly, does anyone know of any existing examples or discussion of this technique?

NOTE: Both pwnedlist.com and shouldichangemypassword.com are apparently run by reputable people/organizations, and I have no reason to believe otherwise. This is more of a thought exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Services like pwnedlist.com are working with public information.  By definition everyone has access to this data,  so attempting to secure it is a moot point.  An attacker will just download it from [The Pirate Bay](http://thepiratebay.org/search/passwords/0/99/0).

However, using a hash function like this is still easy to break because its unsalted and lacks key straighting.  In all reality a message digest function like sha-512 just isn't the right tool for the job.

You are much better off with a [Bloom Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).  This allows you to create a blacklist of leaked data without any possibility of obtaining the plain-text. This is because a permutation based brute force likely to find collisions than real plain text.  Lookups and insertions a cool O(1) complexity,  and the table its self takes up much less space,  maybe 1/10,000th of the space it would using a traditional sql database,  but this value is variable depending on the error rate you specify.